# All fonts lost in xcode?

Tags: xcode, uistoryboard

I have lost all fonts in xcode storyboard.  UILabels,UIButtons, Text fields all show the same thing "No font" and it's dimmed out.  I checked some of the answers and don't have a "Derived Data" folder to delete, which has solve similar problems other users have had.  I have included a screenshot.  Please note I'm not trying to install custom fonts, just get the regular system fonts back.  Thanks in advance for any help. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the XCode hope that will work.